# What is the Significance of "SIXTY YEAR CYCLE"?

Tags: astrology

We have a 60-year cycle namely Prabhava, Vibhava, etc...is there a correlation between this cycle and human life/evolution?

Comment: According to Brihat Samhita, the significance of the 60 year Barhaspatya cycle lies only in predicting annual rainfall (which continues even to this date by the IMD) & overall condition of the kingdom.